# Laravel Memory Issue?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, digital-ocean

[image]

dear all

i am facing such problem on DO server, i have tried everything , the whole site is working 100% properly on linux server using Homestead but after uploading it , it works for one time , going down many times after reloading or refreshing the page .
 - i tried to increase the memory of the apache server
 - i also tried to track the laravel.log but no any issues.
- i also deleted the compiled.php in addition of composer clear-cache + php artisan cache:clear + php artisan optimize but no use.

any ideas ? i would be so thankful.
thank you in advance.

Comment: May be the `memory_limit` issue is here. Check you server `memory_limit` and increase it around *2048M* and check after restart server. OR You can use `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` in your app, instead above.

Comment: Are you using a lot of queues? try to make `ps aux` to see if there is any process consuming your ram. also maybe there is a not well written code, that allocates too much RAM.

Comment: Enable swap memory. By default it's off. And because of Laravel (not only) "eat" much RAM it can cause current problem.

Comment: it's well-written dude , i am using barryvdh/laravel-debugbar even db-query-tracer to trace each query any even every page loading within Milliseconds.

the whole site is working perfectly on homestead , no any errors occured.

Comment: Are you trying to make a continues application (continually-running) ?

Answer (score 3):

Your droplet is running out of memory. Create a swap file to fix this issue.

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Reference: [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer of my question if anyone may encounter this in future.

the server was having some other wordpress sites that was made from the main github repo which does not include the .htaccess , that was somehow consuming server memory.

1- create a .htaccess for each wordpress.
2- add php.ini within each (folder) site with memory_limit 64M or whatever number u would like to use. thank you for ur concern.