# Linux Memory Usage

Tags: linux, laravel, memory

My web application server is using a lot of memory but not using the full 4GB of memory. It's saying that there is only 130 free. Which doesn't make sense since 955 is used. The application framework is Laravel and uses Redis for it's sessions.

Any idea why it won't use the total amount?

[image: Question about memory ussage]

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Laravel Memory Issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236908/laravel-memory-issue)

Answer (score 1):

2.8G are used as `buff/cache`. this means they are used by the kernel as buffers and file system caches, and will be released to user processes if needed.

See this answer for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free

Comment: I upgrade my ram to 8GB and still the same issue. My application will max out at 955-1000M and say that buff/cache is using 6700M.